# Magento: adding pdf invoice to invoice email

Tags: php, email, magento, invoice, magento-1.7

I have been searching for examples the last couple of days and have been trying to do it myself, but I'm stuck at the following.

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.
I want to add the invoice PDF as an attachment to the transactional email when generating the invoice.

I have tried several things including changing /Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php, /Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php and /Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php.

I know which files are involved in the process, I know where to add the attachment, I just can't figure out how to actually generate the PDF and attach it to the email.

It also seems that the way emails are generated has been changed with magento 1.7.0.0 and all explanations are for 1.6.x

I'm also aware that there are several extentions (i.e. FOOMAN's), but I prefer to change the files myself (I want to keep my installation clean of extentions as much as possible).

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Comment: Hi Guus, in the end I didn't manage to do it. I switched to prestashop, magento was a bit to difficult for my purposes. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I searched online for a few hours but the solutions were  for older version of Magento, my version is 1.7.0.2. And the way Magento handled email was changed. Here is the steps how I do this, hope it’s helpful for you.

1) Change app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php

```
Part 1, add protected $emailTemplate; to the top of the class:

class Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer extends Varien_Object
{
/**
* List of email infos
* @see Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info
*
* @var array
*/
protected $_emailInfos = array();

// Add the following one line

protected $emailTemplate;
```

Part 2 update the function send()

```
public function send()
{

// the original was $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
// Change it to the following four lines:

if ($this->emailTemplate)
$emailTemplate = $this->emailTemplate;
else
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

Part 3 add function to the end of the class:

```
public function addAttachment(Zend_Pdf $pdf, $filename){
$file = $pdf->render();

$this->emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');



$attachment = $this->emailTemplate->getMail()->createAttachment($file);
$attachment->type = 'application/pdf';
$attachment->filename = $filename;
}
```

2) Update app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php

```
Update sendEmail function

$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

// the next two lines were added

$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($this));
$mailer->addAttachment($pdf,'invoice.pdf');



if ($notifyCustomer) {
$emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
$emailInfo->addTo($order-
```

Th original url is here :
http://www.ericpan.com/2013/02/14/add-pdf-attachment-to-invoice-email/#.USPAKR2t2-0

Comment: Thx for the solution. I would recommend however to extend the core files, not to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice
```

To see an example of a sales invoice pdf being generated:

```
$pdf = Mage::getModel('sales/order_pdf_invoice')->getPdf(array($invoice));
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice'.Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s').
    '.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```

Now this is actually rendering the PDF to include it in the HTTP response, not saving it out as a file, but there should be a method in the invoice model or abstract pdf model for saving out a pdf.

And then, to add the attachment, you probably want to look at:

```
Zend_Mail::addAttachment()
```

I don't have an example handy, and actually searched Magento 1.7 for any reference to `addAttachment()` and didn't find any!  Interesting.

But hopefully this gives you a little bit of direction.

Comment: thanks for your reply. New information which can help me. I will try again with your info tonight. If I succeed I will post it here! Thanks again and if anybody has some other useful info, let me know!